# ASP.NET MVC WebAPI combining Forms authentication and Basic authentication headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have one problem I'd like to get a piece of an advice about.
We are building an ASP.NET MVC application that will have both: web pages (regular MVC controllers) and WebAPI part for RESTful API used by mobile devices.
Now, web pages will use forms authentication and will have alot of ajax requests. On the other hand, mobiles will use Basic authentication headers against WebAPI.

What I would like to do is allow using both, Forms authentication (for browser/ajax users) and Basic authentication (for mobile requests) on the same WebAPI controller methods.

The reason is that I don't want to duplicate things since many ajax requests will need exactly the same data as mobile web api requests.

So, I was thinking if I should have filters like:

```
[BasicAuthFilter]
[FormsAuthenticationFilter]
MethodInWebAPIController()
```

In that case, method would authenticate regardless where the request came from.

Questions:
1) is that the right way to do it?
2) could someone point me to some code examples of best practices how to do it?

Comment: Normal [Authorize] attribute should work, is it?

Comment: oooh god..this is something asked almost 2 years back. I seriously doubt whether there are any points gained for editing posts. :/